# Can't manipulate and refresh data in child component from event in another component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to refresh markers on a map in one child component from a button click in a different child component. They both have the same parent and I'm emitting the event from the button click and can run the function in the map components needed.

I previously had this working but was all in one component and wanted to divide them out.

My issue is when I try to filter a list of markers by name, it gives me an undefined error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'signs' of undefined

**UPDATE**

I'm now not getting the error previous but something is still very weird. I did totally miss the Arrow functions so maybe I'm missing something here...

I have a list of point objects in my json file called "signs". I'm trying to filter them depending on the district choosen. There is a total of 191 sign. When I press a district, I get the correct 51 points. But when I choose another, it's 0. I understand that it's filtering from the previous filtered list, which is sending back zero...but I don't know why. I thought if I created a variable and set the signs to it, it wouldn't manipulate the signs object directly.

```
<template>
<div>
    <HelloWorld :signs="this.locations"></HelloWorld>
    <MarkerButton v-on:btn-marker="choosenMarker"></MarkerButton>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';
import MarkerButton from './MarkerButton';
import signs from '../utils/standpoints.js';

export default {
    data(){
        return {
            locations: signs,
            markerList: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        choosenMarker(marker) {
            let district = '';

            switch(marker){
                case 'green': 
                    district = 'Cliff Coast';
                    break;
                case 'red': 
                    district = 'Haven Coast';
                    break;
                case 'pink': 
                    district = 'Southern Peninsulas';
                    break;
                case 'yellow': 
                    district = 'Bay Coast';
                    break;
                case 'indigo': 
                    district = 'Surf Coast';
                    break;
                case 'orange': 
                    district = 'Northern Headlands';
                    break;
            }
            // Second time around it will give me 0
            this.locations.points = this.locations.points.filter(x => x.district == district);
            console.log(signs);
            return this.locations;
        },
    },
    components:{
        HelloWorld,
        MarkerButton
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: I think tat the use of an arrow function is not intended here and you are getting parent's "this" (may be the window). I would try with "choosenMarker: function(marker) { ... }" or simply "chooosenMarker(marker) { ... }".

Comment: @MaxOriola - Thanks a million for your help, that clicked right away but I could not see it!! I'm having another issue, maybe the same thing but I'm a bit weary. My list isn't filtering correctly and my watcher in the child component isn't picking up the change :/

Comment: @SmiffyKmc, maybe it should be `:signs="locations"`, remove the `this`?

Comment: Okay, that worked and I was able to see the rest now! The benefit of extra eyes!! Thanks a million guys, it was honestly killing me like.